# Comparing char element in array to an operator

Tags: c, arrays, char, compare, argv

I have been looking all over for how to compare char elements in a char array correctly, but it is not working out for me. I am trying to compare the first char in a char array to an operator (checking to see if a + or -) exists.

**EDIT: Saw my mistake. Logic error in the if statement. Thank you all for such quick responses.**

At first I tried this:

```
    main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i;
    int len;
    char input[10];

    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++){

        len = strlen(argv[i]);
        strcpy(input,argv[i]);

        //debug purposes
        printf("%c\n",input[0]);

        if(input[0] != '+' || input[0] != '-')  {
            printf("incorrect number format. %s has no sign.\nnow terminating.\n", input);
        }// end if
    }//end for
}//end main
```

Then I read some more posts and saw that I should be comparing the chars using strcompare, so then I tried this: `if( !strcmp(input[0],'+') || !strcmp(input[0],'-') )`

However, they still don't seem to be comparing properly. I get a segmentation fault with the above code and with my previous code, it would print the operator, but still go into the if statement saying that the format was incorrect. I am still fairly new to C, so any advice or tips on how I can get these chars to compare correctly will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `strcpy` call is dangerous. If the command-line parameter has more than 9 characters, you will write beyond the bounds of `input` (undefined behaviour). You should better use `strncpy` (or a similar function) or allocate `len + 1` bytes for `input`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic in the original `if` condition is incorrect:

```
if(input[0] != '+' || input[0] != '-')
```

That will always be true: if `'+'== input[0]` the condition equates to `false || true`, and vice versa for `'-' == input[0]`.

It should be:

```
if(input[0] != '+' && input[0] != '-')
```

Comment: You are correct. I should have been using && instead of ||. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You compare *strings* with `strcmp` (that's what it literally means: `str` = "string", `cmp` = compare), not chars. The comparisons in your original code block are fine.

The confusion is probably due to your use of a char array. In C, strings are (largely) equivalent to char arrays, so if you are using a char array as a string then `strcmp` *would* be appropriate. However, you are not doing so: you are using it just as an array of characters, and so your original comparisons are fine.

What you want to do is enter the if block if the operator is not `+` **and** not `-`. You are using an `or` though. Try the following instead:

```
if(input[0] != '+' && input[0] != '-')  {
    printf("incorrect number format. %s has no sign.\nnow terminating.\n", input);
}
```

Comment: if the comparisons in my original code are fine, they why didn't they work? 

edit: just saw why. silly me.

Answer (score 2):

Single characters are compared directly (e.g. `input[0] != '-'`). `strcmp` and friends are for comparison of strings.

But your condition is always true. You want

```
if(input[0] != '+' && input[0] != '-')  {
    ...
```

Comment: You are correct. I should have been using && instead of ||. Thank you.